# MySQL: Want to use a stored procedure to sort table by one column, then use that ordering to set values of another column

Tags: mysql, for-loop, stored-procedures, sql-order-by

Pretty new to SQL, so I apologize if this is obvious.

I have a table of the number of games sold and their corresponding rank in the bestseller list (1,  2, 3, etc.). This table is called ranking(rank: bigint, global_sales: double).

What I want to do is make a stored procedure that I can call whenever the sales update, and then this procedure can be called to update the rankings. Here's what I have so far, and I'm afraid it's probably very incorrect:

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists updateRank;
create procedure updateRank()
begin
    select *
    from ranking
    order by global_sales desc;
    
    declare r bigint default 1;
    
    loop1: loop
        GameRank = r;
        set r=r+1;
    end loop loop1;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

From what I could find here and on Google, I couldn't find anything similar, although this is probably a fairly-common query. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I'm using MySQL Workbench version 8.0 CE

Comment: which version of mysql are you using

Comment: I am using MySQL Workbench version 8.0 CE. It's also 8.0 for the other parts that I haven't really messed with yet. Thanks!

Comment: Note that Workbench is just a client. The interesting thing is the version of the server. If that version is 8 too: MySQL 8 is capable of window functions, in particular `rank()` (or `dense_rank()`). So you don't need to materialize and therefore update the rank. You should instead use a view that includes the ranks. That way you don't have to update the figures, they're always the current ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it in a loop
but also you can do it in a query

Of course i don't know your ölayout of your tables, but thos showws you how you would update

> ```
> CREATE Table ranking (GameRank  INt,global_sales  INT);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO `ranking` VALUES(0,200),(0,300),(0,250),(0,125)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM ranking
> ```
>
> ```
> GameRank | global_sales
> -------: | -----------:
>        0 |          200
>        0 |          300
>        0 |          250
>        0 |          125
> ```

**MYsql 5.x**

> ```
> SET @ranking = 0
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE ranking r 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT @ranking := @ranking + 1 _rank, global_sales FROM ranking ORDER BY global_sales DESC) t  ON  r.global_sales = t.global_sales
>   SET GameRank = _rank
> ```

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM ranking   OrDER By global_sales DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> GameRank | global_sales
> -------: | -----------:
>        1 |          300
>        2 |          250
>        3 |          200
>        4 |          125
> ```

**MYSQL 8**

> ```
> UPDATE ranking r 
> INNER JOIN (SELECT global_sales,RANK() OVER (  ORDER BY global_sales DESC ) my_rank FROM ranking) t  
> ON  r.global_sales = t.global_sales
>   SET GameRank = my_rank
> ```

> 

> ```
> SELECT * FROM ranking   OrDER By global_sales DESC
> ```
>
> ```
> GameRank | global_sales
> -------: | -----------:
>        1 |          300
>        2 |          250
>        3 |          200
>        4 |          125
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=080cbe112b3b7f841dd96691ddfb2504)*